# Shell can't run python in mac

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script in mac below:

```
python Test.py
```

and Test.py is below:

```
import subprocess
import os.path
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, isdir, join
from filecmp import dircmp
import json
import sys
import shutil
....(skip)
```

and I execute "python Test.py" in Mac Terminal,it's ok. 
but I execute "./Test.sh" 
it will get error below:

```
./Test.py: line 1: import: command not found
./Test.py: line 2: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/os
from: can't read /var/mail/os.path
from: can't read /var/mail/filecmp
./Test.py: line 6: import: command not found
./Test.py: line 7: import: command not found
./Test.py: line 8: import: command not found
```

Comment: Why did you edit your question to say `/Test.sh`? From your output it's obvious that this isn't what you're actually running.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your script like `./test.py`, you need a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
# ...
```

This will tell your shell what interpreter it should use to execute that script. You'll also need to make it executable:

```
chmod +x ./test.py
```

See [Using Python on Unix platforms](https://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#miscellaneous).